# Cannot implicity convert type string to System.Func<string,int,string,string>

Tags: c#, string, implicit-conversion

When I use method to replace the one value in a string this works, but it doesn't when I set up a function to do it. The method is almost exactly the same as the func below.
The Func gives the error

> Cannot implicity `string` to `System.Func<string,int,string,string>`.

I know.  I know. Use the method if it works and forget the Func. Just want to know why the Func does not work.  I have spent some time trying different combinations of types without success. I am a newbie just learning C# for fun(?).

```
static Func<string,int,string,string> ReplaceNumber(string p, int location, string newValue)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(p);
    sb.Remove(location, 1);
    sb.Insert(location, newValue);
    string temp = sb.ToString();
    return temp;   // why doesn't "return sb.ToString()" work
}

static string ReplaceNumber(string p, int location, string newValue)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(p);
    sb.Remove(location, 1);
    sb.Insert(location, newValue);
    string temp = sb.ToString();
    return temp;   // why doesn't "return sb.ToString()" work
}
```

Comment: A `string` is not a `Func<string, int, string, string>` - your return type does not match your method signature.

Comment: I read the code about 10 times and didn't see what was missing.  I understood what the problem was and couldn't make it go away.   Like I said, I am new, taking this step by step.  I should have looked at another Func that I had that did work and should have realized what I was missing to make this one work.  Should have, would have, could have.  Thanks for helping me out.  Will delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `Func`  like this:

```
static Func<string, int, string, string> ReplaceNumber = delegate(string p, int location, string newValue)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(p);
    sb.Remove(location, 1);
    sb.Insert(location, newValue);
    return sb.ToString();       
};
```

and call them like :

```
string output = ReplaceNumber("Sample", 1, "sample op3"); // op will be "Ssample op3mple"
```

Note : `return sb.ToString();`  will  work subject to the condition that, the `location` having an integer value which is a valid location inside the string.
Your static method will also do the same task for you:

```
static string ReplaceNumber(string p, int location, string newValue)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(p);
        sb.Remove(location, 1);
        sb.Insert(location, newValue);
        return  sb.ToString();         
    }
```

Comment: Or the more modern approach using an expression `Func<string, int, string, string> ReplaceNumber = (p, location, newValue) => { ... };`

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  I will go back over Func explanations one-more-time to make sure I understand the need for 'delegate'.  I created another Func:  static Func<int,string,int> getNumber = (int k,string m) =>
     {
         string a = "0123456789";
         return a.IndexOf(m[k]);
     };  that did not need the word 'delegate'

Comment: In my second example, I did not notice I had used a '=>' in it.  <slapping forehead and uttering sound of disgust>.  Thanks again for your answers un-lucky and Brad.

Comment: @MadJayhawk - Why are you defining the method this way? Are you dynamically changing it at run-time?

Comment: Enig:  This problem is from SPOJ/the Next Palindrome. I input a number then find then next largest palindrome for that number. 1724 -> 1771 for example. My routine exchanged numbers such as 7 for 2 in the example.  It would be fairly easy except for the fact the given number can have a million digits which means I am forced to use a string/stringbuilder versus using an int array. I solved the problem using an int array but it failed.They probably used a number larger than 2 million to test it.I cannot see another way to get around the size limits using an int imposes on me.  List maybe?